# (SQL Merge) I am getting duplicates in the table

Tags: sql, merge, azure-synapse

We have a daily stream where we are getting the list of customers using various products.

I am trying to create a table for the customers where we can track their changes, and at the same time, we can get a distinct list of customers.

The stream contains thousands of records each day. That was the reason we thought we should move from SCD Type 1 to SCD Type 2.

We want to implement this procedure so that it will run each day and get the records from the last day and compare them to the whole table. If the customer has any change, it will mark that row as 0 and get the new row and mark it as 1.

But in this process, I am getting the new records, but I am also getting duplicate data when I am running the stored procedure.

Please guide.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
Create PROC [dbo].[sp_UpdateCustomerInfoHistory] AS BEGIN
SET
    NOCOUNT ON --Truncate Table [dbo].[CustomerInfoHistory];
    DECLARE @TODAY DATE = GETDATE(); 
    DECLARE @YESTERDAY DATE = GETDATE() - 1;
            WITH CTE AS (
        SELECT 
            DISTINCT(a.CustomerId) AS CustomerId,
            ISNULL(b.[CustomerName], a.[CustomerName]) AS CustomerName,
            ISNULL(b.[CurrentDefaultDomain], a.[CustomerName]) AS CurrentDefaultDomain,
            ISNULL(b.[CustomerCountryCode], 'Unknown') AS CustomerCountryCode,
            ISNULL(b.[HasC], 0) AS HasC,
            ISNULL(b.[HasG], 0) AS HasG,
            ISNULL(b.[IsV], 0) AS IsV,
            ISNULL(
                ISNULL(b.[CustomerCreatedDate], a.[ProductCreatedTimeUtc]),
                @TODAY
            ) AS CustomerCreatedDate,
            ISNULL(b.[CustomerState], 'Active') AS CustomerState,
            ISNULL(b.[CustomerType], 'RegularCustomer') AS CustomerType,
            ISNULL(b.[DataCenterProduct], 'Unknown') AS DataCenterProduct,
            ISNULL(b.[DataCenterModel], 'Unknown') AS DataCenterModel,
            ISNULL(b.[IsTestCustomer], 0) AS IsTestCustomer,
            ISNULL(b.[CommunicationLanguage], 'Unknown') AS CommunicationLanguage,
            ISNULL(b.[IsInternal], 0) AS IsInternal,
            ISNULL(b.[IndustryName], 'N/A') AS IndustryName,
            ISNULL(c.MappingID, 0) AS MappingID
        FROM
            [dbo].[ProductDetails] AS a
            LEFT JOIN [Common].[vwdimCustomer_Staging] AS b ON a.CustomerId = b.CustomerId
            LEFT JOIN [Common].[vwmapCustomerMappingID_Staging] AS c ON b.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
            WHERE a.[TIMESTAMP] = @YESTERDAY
    ), CTE1 AS (
    Select *, BINARY_CHECKSUM(
                CustomerId,
                CustomerName,
                IsTestCustomer,
                IsInternal
            ) AS MKEY
    from CTE)
    MERGE INTO [dbo].[CustomerInfoHistory] AS T USING CTE1 AS S ON T.[MKEY] = S.[MKEY]
    WHEN MATCHED 
    AND [Current_Flag] = 1
    AND T.CustomerName <> S.CustomerName THEN
UPDATE
SET
    T.Current_Flag = 0,
    T.End_date = @YESTERDAY
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
INSERT
    (
        CustomerId,
        CustomerName,
        CurrentDefaultDomain,
        CustomerCountryCode,
        HasC,
        HasG,
        IsV,
        CustomerCreatedDate,
        CustomerState,
        CustomerType,
        DataCenterProduct,
        DataCenterModel,
        IsTestCustomer,
        CommunicationLanguage,
        IsInternal,
        IndustryName,
        MappingID,
        Eff_Date,
        End_Date,
        Current_Flag,
        MKEY,
        RefreshedDate
    )
VALUES
    (
        S.CustomerId,
        S.CustomerName,
        S.CurrentDefaultDomain,
        S.CustomerCountryCode,
        S.HasC,
        S.HasG,
        S.IsV,
        S.CustomerCreatedDate,
        S.CustomerState,
        S.CustomerType,
        S.DataCenterProduct,
        S.DataCenterModel,
        S.IsTestCustomer,
        S.CommunicationLanguage,
        S.IsInternal,
        S.IndustryName,
        S.MappingID,
        @YESTERDAY,
        '12/31/2099',
        1,
        S.MKEY,
        @TODAY
    );
END
```

Comment: Hi @Piyush, please correct me if I understand you wrong in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in Azure Synapse. It will insert new rows or update old rows based on the primary key value.

For example:

1. Create table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.CustomerInfoHistory (
    CustomerId int NOT NULL,
    CustomerName nvarchar(254) NOT NULL,
    CurrentDefaultDomain nvarchar(max) NULL
);
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.CustomerInfoHistory ADD CONSTRAINT PK__kruserpr__6E092EE804688C07 PRIMARY KEY (CustomerId, CustomerName);
GO
```

2. Create a Table-valued parameter named `dbo.CustomerInfoHistory_type`, it will be used in my stored procedure:

```sql
create TYPE dbo.CustomerInfoHistory_type AS TABLE(
    CustomerId int NOT NULL,
    CustomerName nvarchar(254) NOT NULL,
    CurrentDefaultDomain nvarchar(max)
)
GO
```

3. Create a Stored procedure, it will merge the same records and insert new records based on the primary key:

```sql
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

create PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpsertCustomerInfoHistory]

@profile dbo.CustomerInfoHistory_type READONLY

AS

BEGIN

    MERGE dbo.CustomerInfoHistory AS target_sqldb

    USING @profile AS source_tblstg

    ON (target_sqldb.CustomerId = source_tblstg.CustomerId and target_sqldb.CustomerName = source_tblstg.CustomerName )

    WHEN MATCHED THEN

    UPDATE SET

    CurrentDefaultDomain = source_tblstg.CurrentDefaultDomain


    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN

    INSERT (

        CustomerId,

        CustomerName,

        CurrentDefaultDomain

    )

    VALUES (

        source_tblstg.CustomerId,

        source_tblstg.CustomerName,

        source_tblstg.CurrentDefaultDomain
    );

END
GO
```

4. After that, we can execute the stored procedure by following code:

```sql
DECLARE @profileVar AS dbo.CustomerInfoHistory_type;
/* Add data to the table variable. */
INSERT INTO @profileVar (CustomerId, CustomerName, CurrentDefaultDomain) values (1, 'tom','wednesday');
exec  [dbo].[spUpsertCustomerInfoHistory] @profileVar
```

That's all.